# I want to open slide 7, when I reopen Presentation after closing

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to create a macro, where i want to open slide 7, if the last slide viewed is >= slide 7
else open presentation with slide 1

Comment: Hi! Please share the code that you're working on so that we can help you further. StackOverFlow is not a substitute to write your code. To help you get started, use `OnSlideShowPageChange`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.